# Pinch functionality like on Instagram

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, pinchzoom

I'm trying to translate Instagram's image pinch functionality to Flutter. I'm struggling with:

- possibility to pinch up the image overlaying all other objects (even above the navigation bar)
- <del>after pinch interaction the image goes back to normal size</del> (done)

I'm grateful for any help.

(see [Overlay pinched image above everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745931/overlay-pinched-image-above-everything?noredirect=1#comment112724452_63745931))

Comment: Have you attempted to have a `Stack` with a hidden image that only shows up when you start pinching and transfer the pinch values from the original to the "overlay"?

Comment: Have you tried the package pinch_zoom_image from flutter. https://pub.dev/packages/pinch_zoom_image

Comment: @Rajesh: I'm trying to do it (pinching) without using any package since Flutter implemented it already (since v1.2).

Comment: @João Soares: I hoped there is a more elegant way to work it out. But thank you for the suggestion.