# Overlay pinched image above everything

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to overlay an image during max scaling (I'm using the class *InteractiveViewer*) on top of other objects (also the status bar). Basically like on Instagram. I couldn't find anything reading the docs. A hint on how to proceed?

```
child: InteractiveViewer(
 transformationController: controller,
 maxScale: 2.0,
 minScale: 2.0,
 child: imageBig,
 fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
),
```

Comment: Do you want to  display in a manner in which instagram displays in a popup manner , when you long press it?

Comment: @Aman Verma: nope. I just want to resize the image like it's done on Instagram. When you scale up an image on Instagram it overlays other objects, even the status bar.

Comment: okay that zooming effect  , i will try

Comment: You can increase the `maxScale` to a bigger value to get that effect @spamup

Comment: @void: It doesn't work. The image doesn't overlay on top of other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this issue on flutter repository:

> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66111

You can achive that by using `OverlayEntry` Class, which will handle the rendering of your `InteractiveViewer` child widget over the other widgets.

Also, you can find here a code snippet for `InteractiveViewerOverlay` widget, that you can use directly inside your project.

> https://gist.github.com/zzterrozz/623531eef065a31470e85175c744c986

created by:

1. https://github.com/PixelToast
2. https://github.com/zzterrozz

Edited:
Here is an example for the `InteractiveViewerOverlay` widget and how to use it.

First, the `InteractiveViewerOverlay` widget

```
class InteractiveViewerOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double maxScale;

  const InteractiveViewerOverlay({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    this.maxScale,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InteractiveViewerOverlayState createState() =>
      _InteractiveViewerOverlayState();
}

class _InteractiveViewerOverlayState extends State<InteractiveViewerOverlay>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  var viewerKey = GlobalKey();
  Rect placeholder;
  OverlayEntry entry;
  var controller = TransformationController();
  Matrix4Tween snapTween;
  AnimationController snap;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    snap = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    snap.addListener(() {
      if (snapTween == null) return;
      controller.value = snapTween.evaluate(snap);
      if (snap.isCompleted) {
        entry.remove();
        entry = null;
        setState(() {
          placeholder = null;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    snap.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget buildViewer(BuildContext context) {
    return InteractiveViewer(
        key: viewerKey,
        transformationController: controller,
        panEnabled: false,
        maxScale: widget.maxScale ?? 2.5,
        child: widget.child,
        onInteractionStart: (details) {
          if (placeholder != null) return;

          setState(() {
            var renderObject =
                viewerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            placeholder = Rect.fromPoints(
              renderObject.localToGlobal(Offset.zero),
              renderObject
                  .localToGlobal(renderObject.size.bottomRight(Offset.zero)),
            );
          });

          entry = OverlayEntry(
            builder: (context) {
              return Positioned.fromRect(
                rect: placeholder,
                child: buildViewer(context),
              );
            },
          );

          Overlay.of(context).insert(entry);
        },
        onInteractionEnd: (details) {
          snapTween = Matrix4Tween(
            begin: controller.value,
            end: Matrix4.identity(),
          );
          snap.value = 0;
          snap.animateTo(
            1,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            curve: Curves.ease,
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var viewer = placeholder != null
        ? SizedBox.fromSize(size: placeholder.size)
        : buildViewer(context);

    return Container(
      child: viewer,
    );
  }
}
```

Next, An example of implementing the `InteractiveViewerOverlay` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: ListView(children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border:
                            Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 60,
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Text('Abdelazeem Kuratem',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      Text('5 min', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    ])),
                InteractiveViewerOverlay(
                  child: Image.network(
                    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg",
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[50],
                      border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          _createBottomButton(
                              text: 'Like',
                              icon: Icons.thumb_up,
                              onPressed: () {}),
                          _createBottomButton(
                              text: 'Comment',
                              icon: Icons.comment,
                              onPressed: () {}),
                          _createBottomButton(
                              text: 'Share',
                              icon: Icons.share,
                              onPressed: () {}),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ])),
    );
  }

  Widget _createBottomButton({
    String text,
    IconData icon,
    Null Function() onPressed,
  }) {
    return FlatButton.icon(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      icon: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.green,
        size: 21,
      ),
      label: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 14),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how to implement the InteractiveViewerOverLay widget? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. But my status bar is still visible, although transparent. I used "

onInteractionStart: (details) {
          SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);..."

but this leads the entire screen to shake for a short moment.

Comment: Also, where is the method remove()? 

"The method 'remove' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: remove()"

Comment: InteractiveViewer still doesn't support overlaying on the status bar and the navbar, so the issue still open on Github.
but this solution for overlaying InteractiveViewer above any other widget inside the tree, so it will take the whole screen space when you scale it.
we are waiting until the Futter team adds this feature to the "InteractiveViewer" widget.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. What about the missing method?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not facing this error in my code so it might be a mistake in your code

Comment: The method is being called in the code you've provided. Have you read it at all or did you just use without understanding what's inside?

Comment: @spamup how did you do it...my image is not even zooming out of container..how did you achieve it. please share code snippet

Comment: Its not working for me...i literally copied your code